# Suppress ad banners on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Please suppress advertising banners on the iOS app for users that wouldn't see them on the main sites. Alternatively, allow for in-app-purchase to allow us to support development without spending screen real estate on ad banners.

<sub>I'm fine testing them for a bit, but would rather not see them much or without specifically enabling them on the app.</sub>

Comment: Where do you see ad banners? I haven't noticed any.

Comment: Careers 2.0 has a very tasteful ad in the feed for me at present. Oddly, it opens what looks to be a uiwebview that dumps me at careers.stackexchange.com and a log in screen, but perhaps the log in credentials are not supposed to transfer yet/ever).